# REGEX for `http://google.com/%%PID%%`

Tags: html

I need to check for following pattern in HTML5 `http://example.com/%%PID%%`.
I basically need to make sure that the URL ends with `%%PID%%`.
I'm trying to achieve this functionality using an REGEX expression, but I can't get it to work. Could anybody help me with the REGEX pattern I need to make?

Comment: Can you give some examples of valid and invalid inputs, as well as what you've tried before? We'd like to see some research effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just match

```
/%%PID%%$/
```

% isn't a special character, and the $ there means the end of the line. If I'm reading this correctly, it's a very simple problem.

If you are trying to match those slashes and everything, you'll need to escape them:

```
/http:\/\/google\.com\/%%PID%%$/
```

Then, if you want to match something that starts with http... and ends with %%PID%%, like so:

```
/http:\/\/google\.com\/.*%%PID%%$/
```

Where '.' means "any character" and '*' means "0 or more of the preceding character" so '.*' means "0 or more of anything"

Comment: Rather `/%%PID%%$/D` not to match new line at the end.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'D' flag, and that $ will not actually match the new line, just the end of the line.